# confused about using is or are

Tags: grammar, tense

In the following sentence I am confused about using "is" or "are":(disregard the meaning, it is just an example)

Do not change your clothes when the door or the window *is* open

Do not change your clothes when the door or the window *are* open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically you are confused in SVA (Subject-Verb Agreement) and the usage of conjunctions like 'or' and 'and'.

Let me break your sentence to explain:

> Do not change your clothes when the door ***is*** open
>   Do not change your clothes when the window ***is*** open

Now, we'll use both 'or' and 'and' in your sentence. As 'or' is a conjunction that comes with the singular verb, we need to use 'is'. More information about the usage of 'or' is [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/or).

So, in your example,

> Do not change your clothes when the door **or** the window **is** open.

Similarly, 'and' conjunction involves all the aspects, and therefore, the verb 'are' is used there. More information on 'and' is [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/and).

> Do not change your clothes when the door **and** the window **are** open.

Here, we don't consider 'clothes' for deciding the verb. You can note it easily.

Hope this will clear your doubt.